# PHP Form Redirect to error link

Tags: php, forms

Using HTML form with action = "www.google.com", but it redirect to link including localhost/www.google.com . My example code is for your reference. Please anyone help me.

My Forms as follows :

```
<form method="POST" action="www.google.com">
  <p>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </p>
  <p>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p>
<label for="comments">Comments:</label>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send Comments">
  </p>
</form>
```

But, the file when click send button, it redirects to 
" http://localhost/basic/www.google.com" error page. Can any one suggest me to resolve the issue.

Comment: what exactly you trying by `action = 'www.google.com'`

Comment: Add the protocol: `action="_https:_/_/_www.google.com". Your computer cannot distinguish this action from a valid resource inside your file system unless you specify the protocol.

Comment: Use `action = "https://www.google.com"`

Comment: You are using relative path in action field.

Comment: no if i add " action="google.com" , it redirects to "http://localhost/basic/google.com" instead of https://google.com

Comment: Hi GMC, still showing another error as : " 405. That’s an error.

The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL /. That’s all we know."

Comment: Why are you even trying to point it to Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to send `POST` request directly to google.com. Why do you want to do this? In the `action` argument you should have own script which can process request from your form.

Comment: Great, Thanks. I will make a change. I done this as a trail and not think about the logic what you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `form` action

**From**

`action="www.google.com"`

**To actual link**

`action="https://www.google.com"`